# Adjusting UIView after loading from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uistoryboard

I have a custom `UIView` class called `MyView` that I use together with a `UIViewController` configured through the storyboard. The majority of the view properties is configured through the Interface Builder; however, I need to adjust a couple of images programmatically before setting them as backgrounds for my button, like this:

```
-(void)setupVisuals {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"myButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)];
    // _myButton is an IBOutlet property set through the storyboard:
    [_myButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The problem is that I cannot call `[self setupVisuals]` from the initializer<sup>*</sup>, because `_myButton` is `nil` at that time.

I solved the problem by adding this line to `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:`

```
[(MyView*)self.view setupVisuals];
```

With this call in place, everything works fine. However, this feels like a work-around, rather than a solution to what is likely a relatively common problem.

Is there a `UIView` method to override, or any other mechanism to complete the initialization of `MyView`'s visuals without tapping into the `viewDidLoad:` mechanism?

---

<sup>*</sup> In this case, the initializer is `initWithCoder:` because the view is loaded from the storyboard. I verified that the initializer gets called correctly, but the visuals are not ready yet.

Comment: IIRC `initWithFrame:` is called even if loading from a NIB/XIB. From there, after a call to `super`, can't you do this? I remember having a similar problem and I resolved it, but I don't remember what/how exactly it was.

Comment: In these cases I usually just do the "initialization" in `viewWillAppear`, but if there is a cleaner way to handle it, I would like to know.  Basically when is the view loaded from the storyboard with all of its outlets intact?

Comment: Did you try just [self.myView setupVisuals] from the viewWillAppear method in your viewController? If you initialized that view in IB and set it as an outlet this should work.

Comment: @DanF That's exactly what OP wants to avoid. Setting up a view should be done inside from the class, not from the view controller. (That would violate encapsulation.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I tried providing `initiWithFrame:`, but it does not get called when the view is loaded from a storyboard :(

Comment: @H2CO3 OHHHH, I missed that it is trying to be done inside the view class, not he view controller.  I still am interested in knowing how this could be done

Comment: @MarkM I am calling it from `viewDidLoad:`, and it works fine; I am sure it would work if I called it from `viewWillAppear:`, but calling it from the view controller is precisely what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Since the viewController is what is "controlling" its subviews there is no reason not to manipulate the viewControllers subviews directly from the controller. This is exactly exactly how you should be handling this. The exception is with layouts such as setting frames, drawRect, etc. from inside the UIView itself. Even if you are wishing to pass the view an object this should still be done from the viewController itself then handled in the UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `viewDidLoad:` correctly.  According to Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You usually override this method to perform additional initialization
>   on views that were loaded from nib files.

If your goal is to encapsulate this functionality at the `UIView` level, try [`layoutSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews).